# git not recognized on first run in command prompt (Windows). Second run works

Tags: git, command-prompt, git-lfs

I've run into a strange problem debugging a python script. I think I have isolated the problem to the follow issue:

When trying to use git trough the command line, I get an error on the first run. Starting with the second run the same command goes through fine.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively, here is the code:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd /d "D:\..."

D:\...>git status

'status is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'

D:\...>git status

On branch SCONS
Your branch is up-to-date....
```

Update: Still no progress. The issue originally came from a git-lfs command. If this maybe helps: git-lfs commands will give an error (even repeatedly) until the command "git" is entered once. After the first failed attempt both git, and git-lfs commands work fine. See picture:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Could you copy & paste the text instead of making a screenshot of it?

Comment: sure! I added it above.

Comment: Where is git installed?  Is it on a network drive?  I could see something like this happening in that kind of environment--though still unusual.

Comment: Does it do the same when using Git Bash? Git Bash usually takes a second or two to intialize, I'm wondering if it is doing some initial set up before you can run git commands?

Comment: It is not installed on a network drive.

Comment: It works right away if I open the repo in Git Shell. I don't know about Git Bash.